# In R programming can we have if inside for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

In R programming can we have if inside for loop

```
for(i in 1:length(abc)){
  print(i)
  if(){}
}
```

this code is giving error I don't know why

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Empty conditions in `if` are not allowed:

```
> if(){}
Error: unexpected ')' in "if()"
```

Use `TRUE` if you want the block to always be executed, or `FALSE` if you never want it executed:

```
> if(TRUE){}
NULL
>
```

There's no problem with this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example you can have

for(i in 1:10){

```
if (i<5)
{print(i)}
else 
{print(i+10)}
```

}

Which prints the following.

[1] 1

[1] 2

[1] 3

[1] 4

[1] 15

[1] 16

[1] 17

[1] 18

[1] 19

[1] 20